# Android custom ListView with ArrayAdapter passing boolean

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-custom-view

I'm new in Android, and I have a problem with sending my boolean flag to my custom ListView class which extends ArrayAdapter...
my code:

```
public class FriendListView extends ArrayAdapter {
    private final Activity context;
    private final ArrayList<String> photo_url;
    private final ArrayList<String> friend_name;

    private final ArrayList<String> id;
    private final Boolean online;

    public FriendListView(Activity context, ArrayList<String> photo_url, ArrayList<String> friend_name, ArrayList<String> id, Boolean online) {
        super(context, R.layout.friend_view, friend_name);

        this.context = context;
        this.photo_url = photo_url;
        this.friend_name = friend_name;
        this.id = id;
        this.online = online;

        Log.d("VK_LIST_VIEW", "online => " + online); //here is normall pass
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_view, null, true);

        Log.d("VK_POSITION_INDEX", photo_url.get(position));

        TextView txt_friend = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt_friend);

        Log.d("VK_LIST_VIEW_2", "online => " + online); //here I can't acces passed value

        //on friend selecting
        txt_friend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {@Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("VK_", "friend selected => " + friend_name.get(position) + " id => " + id.get(position) + " is online => " + online);
            }
        });

        txt_friend.setText(friend_name.get(position));
        //show image from url into ImageView
        Picasso.with(context).load(photo_url.get(position)).transform(new CircleTransform()).into((ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img_photo));
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

I'm passing `online` flag from another class with the second code:

```
adapter = new FriendListView(Logged.this, photo_url, friendArray, friend_id, online);
```

so how I can getting online flag as I pass it to arrayadapter(i.e online = true, then I get true in adapter)? Now it is not so....

Can anyone help with solution?

Comment: describe your `problem`?

Comment: When you say 'I can't acces passed value' what do you mean? Does the compiler throw an error? Or has the value changed?

Comment: @Abbas no, compiler doesn't throw any error, value always is false in `Log.d("VK_LIST_VIEW_2", "online => " + online);`

Comment: @vladimir Add complete class code.

Comment: @Abbas it's full class code, if you mean FriendListView

Comment: plz check when call your adapter, is the value of online changes or not in your main class

Comment: make sure your online is not declare as final in your adapter class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologize for my English.

How did you `setAdapter()`?

I assume that you create  a `ListView` which can show friend `detail(photo,name,id,weather he is online)`

But I don't understand why you use `Boolean online`? Should it be `List<Boolean>`?Because not all friend are online ,or not online.

I think it's better to use JavaBean,it's easy ,you can google it.
If you use javaBean,it will be clearly

Answer (score -1):

You can also make a `List` and save that `boolean` value:

```
private List<Boolean> onlineList = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then in the `constructor` save the value as:

```
this.onlineList.add(online);
```

and later in `getView` you can use it as::

```
boolean isOnline = this.onlineList.get(position);
```